KDE dolphin freezing, crashing, unable to copy
I have Kubuntu 22.04, KDE 5.24.7, and Dolphin 21.12.3. I've been using Kubuntu since June, 2022, and until the last few months I had NO issues with Dolphin or the issues I'm about to describe.
I have another computer on my local network that has Windows 7 and a shared drive. I have this drive mounted on the Kubuntu computer using /etc/fstab.
//10.0.0.5/shared                 /mnt/shared          cifs   credentials=/home/myuser/.secrets/my_cred,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,uid=user1,    0 0

There are no issues connecting to the shared drive or opening files on it. Here is what I've observed:

Sometimes when I have a file open (Libreoffice doc, image, etc.) from the shared drive, I can't save over the file (overwrite the file using "Save"). It says there's some sort of permissions issue, and I have do do a "Save As". But this doesn't happen every time.

When I try to copy a file on the shared drive and paste it on the shared drive, Dolphin  says "the process for the file protocol died unexpectedly". It will create the file where I'm trying to paste it, but the file is 0 bytes, and the KDE notification that a file copy is in progress appears, but I can't stop it. Dolphin hangs/freezes/locks up in this state, and no matter what I try I can't kill dolphin. I've tried:
 $ sudo lsof /mnt/shared

 $ sudo kill -9 <pid>



to close the open files, and the processes die but then instantaneously restart.
I've also tried killing them with the Gnome System Monitor and htop, but again the processes immediately restart. I've tried killing dolphin when it gets in this state, and no matter what I try the process just will not die.
I've also tried to unmount the share when it's in this state, but it says it can't because "Target is busy". If I can't kill the open files, I don't think there's any way to unmount it.
I don't understand why these issues recently started. Before this everything was working perfectly. I could overwrite files, copy files, etc. with no issues.
